# Условные выражения: not x или x == False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

В python существует два варианта проверки отрицательного условия:

```
if not x:
```

```
if x == False:
```

Какой из этих двух вариантов лучше на предмет удобочитаемости и/или быстродействия?

Comment: правильно - первый. Потому что делать сравнение типа ``False == False`` или ``True == False`` - излишне. А именно это и написано во втором варианте.

Comment: @Эникейщик, в смысле излишне? Чем это плохо?

Comment: потому что результат False == False и True == False очевиден. Если у вас с левой стороны логическое значение, то зачем его сравнивать с другим логическим значением. Допустим, слева у вас True. Зачем его сравнивать с False, если просто ``if not True`` дает абсолютно такой же результат без операции сравнения

Comment: `(x == False) == True` хорошо смотрится. Заметьте что можно их менять местами: `(x == True) == False`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy интересная хрень

Comment: @insolor, я с этой хрени бешусь непрерывно. В случае `a < x < b` она выглядит привлекательно. Но парсер поступает так со всеми "операциями сравнения". Получается отдельная категория привилегированных операций про которую надо помнить что в ассоциативные цепочки они не складываются.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ответиь на этот вопрос нам поможет [PEP 285](https://peps.python.org/pep-0285/):

> It has been suggested that, in order to satisfy user expectations, for every x that is considered true in a Boolean context, the expression x == True should be true, and likewise if x is considered false, x == False should be true. In particular newbies who have only just learned about Boolean variables are likely to write
>
> `if x == True:` ...
>
> instead of **the correct form**,
>
> `if x:` ...

Сокращенный перевод:

*В частности, новички, которые только что узнали о логических переменных, скорее всего напишут `if x == True:` вместо **правильной формы** `if x:`*

Answer (score 6):

Прежде всего, вариант

```
if x == False:
```

очень некрасивый —  объект `False` является одиночкой (singleton, единственным объектом), потому вместо оператора `==` (то же самое *значение*) рекомендуется применить оператор `is` (тот же самый *объект*):

```
if x is False:
```

Из [PEP 8 — руководства по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#section-31):

> Сравнения с None должны обязательно выполняться с использованием операторов is или is not, а не с помощью операторов сравнения.

Не совсем правильный перевод. В [английском оригинале](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) стоит немножко другое:

> Сравнения **с одиночками как** None должны обязательно выполняться с использованием операторов is или is not, а не с помощью операторов сравнения.

---

Теперь, команды

- `if x is False:`
- `if not x:`

не всегда идентичны - в команде `if` например пустой словарь вычисляется как `False`:

```
x = {}

if x is False:
    print("1. x is False")    # не выполнится

if not x:
    print("2. not x")         # выполнится
```

---

Ну и теперь к вашим вопросам:

1. **Удобочитаемость** — сравните:

   - `if (option in (1, 5, 6)) is False:` и
   - `if not option in (1, 5, 6):`

   Удобочитаемость зависит от того, кто это читает.;-) Для меня это второй вариант.
2. **Быстродействие:**

   ```
   option = 4

   %timeit if (option in (1, 5, 6)) is False: pass
   %timeit if not option in (1, 5, 6): pass
   ```

   > ```
   > 161 ns ± 3.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
   > 139 ns ± 1.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
   > ```

   Второй вариант чуть-чуть быстрее. Но не убедительно. По моему,  интерпретатор Питона просто заранее не обнаружил совпадение, не оптимизировал первый вариант.

Comment: Кстати, я предпочитаю форму `if x not in y`, в ней сложнее сделать ошибку с порядком операций, да и чисто по-человечески мне кажется она как-то понятнее.

Comment: @CrazyElf, вы на 100% прав, но такого варианта в вопросе не было.;-)

Comment: В вопросе не было, а в вашем ответе есть if not x in y, вот я и упомянул )

Comment: @CrazyElf, но мое `if not (x in y)` соответствует образцу `if not что-то`, а ваше, хоть и красивое, нет. Именно по этой причине я его в своем ответе не употребил.

Answer (score 5):

Прогнав такую проверку:

```
from time import perf_counter
from random import randint


def eq_compare(x):
    return x == False


def not_compare(x):
    return not x


lst = [[], {}, (), 1, 2, 3, True, None] + [randint(0, 10_000) for _ in range(1000)]

s = perf_counter()
for i in lst * 1000:
    eq_compare(i)
print(perf_counter() - s)

s = perf_counter()
for i in lst * 100:
    not_compare(i)
print(perf_counter() - s)
```

Скорость проверки через оператор `not` выше, чем через оператор равенства в 10+ раз.
Вот несколько замеров (попарно):

== : 0.11482529999921098

not: 0.009857600030954927

== : 0.12146590003976598

not: 0.009981999988667667

== : 0.11241040000459179

not: 0.01083189999917522

Считаю, что медленность проверки через == обусловлена динамической типизацией - труднее динамически конвертировать типы в bool, так ещё потом и значения сравнивать.

Comment: Зачем сравнивать производительность если у операции разный смысл? Сравните `[] == False` и `not []`.